# Cannot Find Symbol getHomeTimeline()

Tags: java, jsp, twitter4j

I'm trying to use the [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en) on a JSP test page that I'm beginning to work with, using this code:

```
<%-- Includes --%>
<%@page import="twitter4j.Status"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="twitter4j.TwitterFactory"%>
<%@page import="twitter4j.Twitter"%>
<%@page import="twitter4j.api.TimelineMethods"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <%
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            List<Status> statuses = getHomeTimeline();
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that Netbeans is telling me that at the line 19(the `getHomeTimeline` one) he can't find the symbol. What should I do to correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `twitter.getHomeTimeLine();`?

Comment: Ops. Sorry, I missed the `twitter.` Thanks very much